# Oracle PL/SQL Developer doesn't support cyrillic symbol Instead of cyrillic symbols it showed?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

Oracle PL/SQL Developer don't support cyrillic symbol.
���� are displayed instead of Cyrillic.

Register: NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) or [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqldeveloper-landing.html)?

Comment: The screenshot shows **Allround Automations** PL/SQL Developer, not an Oracle product.